# Getting 16 bytes at a time from .txt

Tags: java, string, network-programming, byte

I Have two files one sending, one receiving.  I have the connection between the two.

can send text with :

```
// Prepare a message 
 messageToSend = "text that is sent";
 lengthMessageToSend = messageToSend.length(); 
 sendingBuffer = messageToSend.getBytes();


// Send the message
 myLink.sendFrame(sendingBuffer, lengthMessageToSend);
 System.out.println(lengthMessageToSend);
```

And Receive with :

```
// Display the message
  messageReceived = new String(receivingBuffer, 0, lengthMessageReceived);
  System.out.println("Message received is: [" + messageReceived + "]"); 

// Prepare a message  
  messageToSend = "1";
  lengthMessageToSend = messageToSend.length(); 
  sendingBuffer = messageToSend.getBytes();

 // Send the message
  myLink.sendFrame(sendingBuffer, lengthMessageToSend);
```

The text I am trying to now send is from a .txt, but just to send 16 bytes at a time within a payload:

[ SEQ | LEN | PAYLOAD | CHECKSUM ]    --> for a total Header of 19 bytes.

What would the best way of doing this ?

Just reading in 16 bytes(8 characters) at a time?? If so How?

Comment: Why? This is horrifically inefficient. You should send at least several K at a time. @CodeWhisperer This is trivially easy in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop and increment `i` by 16 each time, this `i` represents the start of the `messageToSend.getBytes()` offset - then put the next 16 bytes (from `i` to `i+16`, handling the case when there are less than 16 bytes left) into the 'packet' and send it off.

Also use an explicit encoding with `getBytes()` or environment settings may result in 'unexpected behavioral changes'.

Such a basic implementation might look something like:

```
byte[] data = messageToSend.getBytes("UTF-8"); // Specify encoding!

// "For all data, stepping by 16 bytes at a time.."
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i += 16) {
   // How many bytes actually remain (or 16 if more than 16 remain)
   var frameSize = Math.min(16, data.length - i);

   // Construct frame data from data in i..i+frameSize and send.
   // If you want to ALWAYS send 16 bytes, update as appropriate.
   byte[] frameData = new byte[frameSize];
   System.arraycopy(data, i, frameData, 0, frameSize);

   sendFrame(frameData, frameSize);
}
```

The code will have to be adapted to add a sequence number, but that shouldn't be hard as it's always incremented by one.

The reading happens similary: consume the packet header and process the remaining buffer (which may include the start of the next packet) according to the length/framing data.

```
// Assuming new frames are always copied-to-start and that there
// if a complete frame ready (can be determined from frame size with)
// two reads. If not, keep reading..
byte[] receivingBuffer = ..;
int offset = 0;
int seq = receivingBuffer[offset++];
int frameSize = receivingBuffer[offset++];

// Again, use an encoding
String content = new String(receivingBuffer, offset, frameSize, "UTF-8");
offset += frameSize;

int checksum = receivingBuffer[offset++];

// Use offset to move extra data in receivingBuffer to start
// of buffer to make it easy to reset offset to 0 and repeat above.
```

Comment: So then send again after a [ACK] has come back as a [1], how would i send the next part of the message?

Comment: @Bailey507 You don't have to wait to send the next bit.

Comment: @Bailey507 Note that the posted code is *only* reliably works when the Unicode splits the frame size boundary exactly. This will normally hold for UTF-16 (except surrogate pairs) and will hold for English in UTF-8. Otherwise you'll have to rejoin the frame data (or send only whole UTF encoded sequences) as appropriate before decoding the string.